# Box OAuth2: Alert Users before 60 day refresh token?

Tags: oauth-2.0, box-api

I have a 3rd-party app that connects to Box using the API/OAuth2 implementation.  Is there a way within the Box OAuth2 implementation to know which users need to get a new refresh_token before their 60 days is up?  I'd like to send them an email reminder to re-grant my app access to their Box accounts a few days before it expires.

Comment: In your 3rd-party app, are you able to store the time that the user initially authenticated? If so, then you can easily calculate an approximate expiration date/time for the refresh token. If you are storing this information on your server's side then rather than sending your users an email to reauthenticate you can just get a new refresh token. Here's what the API docs say:

Comment: "The access_token is the actual string needed to make API requests. Each access_token is valid for 1 hour. In order to get a new, valid token, you can use the accompanying refresh_token. Each refresh_token is valid for one use in 60 days. Every time you get a new access_token by using a refresh_token, we reset your timer for the 60 day period and hand you a new refresh_token. This means that as long as your users use your application once every 60 days, their login is valid forever." https://developers.box.com/oauth/